# bootstrap 4 positioning icon left and right side in table cells

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place icons in table's cells (in right side and in left side) in bootstrap v4.
 
To do this I used absolute positioning in this way:

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="one" class="table table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-xs-right">
                        Left Icon Position<span class="left-icon-pos"><i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Right Icon Position<span class="right-icon-pos"><i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
.right-icon-pos {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
.left-icon-pos {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}
```

This solution works well, but I have a problem when I resize the window, the icon being positioned absolutely does not take up space and is displayed above the text.
How can I have the same effect so that when I resize the window the icons appear side by side to the text?
All solutions are welcome (even without using absolute positioning).
Thanks

[My bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/0mteRexdMq)

Comment: `float` the icons instead of positioning them absolutely

Comment: add some `padding-left` and `padding-right` to left `th` and right `th` elements respectively

Comment: @JacobGray - with float the icons are not positioned aligned horizontally to the text

Comment: @tmg - This might be a good solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has helper classes "pull-left" and "pull-right". If you add those to your "left-icon-position" and "right-icon-position" classes and get rid of the "position: absolute" you should be all set!

So the first one would look like this:
span class="left-icon-pos pull-left"

Comment: I already tried this solution and in this way the icons are not positioned aligned horizontally to the text. :(

Comment: So when the screen size is very small, are you wanting the text to wrap rather than the icon + the text wrapping? Then maybe the easiest would be to put the icon in it's own cell, and have no border in between the left icon and left text, and between the right icon and right text, so it appears to be a single cell?

Comment: You may also do so, but the solution proposed by tmg seems better and simpler. Thank you